# How much space will the Ubuntu 10.04 netbook take after installation......is it compatible with the Archos 9?

Tags: system-installation, tablet, ubuntu-netbook

I wanted to install Ubuntu on my Archos 9, which currently has Windows 7 starter. Is it possible to get onscreen keyboard with d default key on archos??

How much space does Ubuntu take up after installation?

Answer (score 2):

Had a quick look around this seems to be quite a comprehensive guide on how to do it

http://www.ossramblings.com/installing-ubuntu-archos-9-tablet

In that guide they use a netbook install of Ubuntu not sure how much space that takes up normally but I know the system requirement for the desktop version is 5Gb so would think the netbook version would be a bit less.